# Haskell State Monad Syntax

Tags: haskell

What is the Syntax to test this code sample in haskell?

```
type Estate1 x = ([Int], Map x Int)

pop :: State (Estate1 Int) Int
pop = do
  (liste,key) <- get
  return ((Map.!) key 1)
```

Comment: You can use `runState` where you pass an initial state, and you retrieve the "output" and the state after you "run" the state monad.

Comment: could u write the Syntax my problem is the Syntax for Estate how to write it

Comment: It's the same syntax as any function call.

Comment: @Kenneth: Syntax is *not* the problem. Haskell has no complex syntax at all. In fact, except for some languages like Prolog, it has one of the most minimalistic grammars possible. It is nearly all a matter of functions. If you each time handle the cases as if it is something "specific", then then you eventually have a hard time to figure out new things. Instead of learning "specific" syntax, I adcise to lear exactly *what* you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

```
runState pop ([1,2,3], Map.singleton 1 42)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                 initial state
```

Try it in ghci, you'll see what it returns.